# Magento 2 Products Base Image Missing on Frontend after Import

Tags: magento2, product-images, importexport, image-upload

We've been having an issue with importing images via CSV spreadsheet into Magento 2.
I'm able to import product images into the Magento admin via the columns Base Image, Small Image, Thumbnail and Swatch - however it doesn't show on the product frontend. However, it shows just fine on the catalog pages. Screenshots attached.
[image: Product image imported into admin]
[image: Product image does not show on frontend]
[image: The thumbnail displays fine on catalog pages]

I've tried the following commands:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:clean

php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

But none of them fix the issue. The product main image works when manually added via the admin.
What could be causing this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also attempted the following command already, with no success: php bin/magento catalog:image:resize

Comment: php bin/magento catalog:images:resize try this command then run all command

Comment: Did that again - still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The images were displaying correctly on an incognito window, so likely the fix was:

`php bin/magento catalog:image:resize`

followed by an image cache clear from the admin.